# react native - What should I do each time <textinput> is input, so <Google> in </NavigationContainer> cannot be re-rendered?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

App.tsx

```js
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const searchHandler = () => {
        setSearch(text)
    }

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <View style={styles.case1}></View>
            <View style={styles.case1}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='search'
                    onChangeText={(val) => setText(val)}

                />
                <Button
                    onPress={searchHandler}
                    title="search button"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                />
            </View>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="google1" component={() => <Google item={search} />} />
                <Tab.Screen name="google2" component={() => <Google2 item={search} />} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Google.tsx

```js
export default function google(props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.webContainer}>
            <WebView
                source={{
                    uri:
                        'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03BNJhsVEURZyXdlkOpk1l1qb2Nug%3A1595674787434&source=hp&ei=oxAcX4qzGLLxhwOhw5jwBA&q=' + props.item + '&oq=' +** props.item ** +'&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCC4QkwIyAggAMgIIADICCC4yAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgjECc6BQguEJECOgUIABCRAjoICC4QxwEQowI6BwguEEMQkwI6CAguEMcBEK8BUPEDWOkHYKwIaABwAHgAgAGMAYgBigOSAQMwLjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjKkIXnn-jqAhWy-GEKHaEhBk4Q4dUDCAc&uact=5'
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

I'm creating an app that searches across different sites by typing in the search bar.

Whenever I type in  the web-view keeps re-rendering. I only want to be re-rendered(Google web-view) when I click the search button.

I've heard that should use use-memo, Callback, as far as I know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchHandler = () => {
    setSearch(text) <- "text" is a reference 
}
```

try

```
const searchHandler = () => {
    setSearch(`${text}`) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent rerender `WebView` from props through `useMemo`. (memoization)

```js
export default function google(props) {
    const Web = React.useMemo(() => {
                  return <WebView source={{uri: 'abc'}} />
                }, [])
    return (
        <View style={styles.webContainer}>
          {Web}
        </View>
    );
};
```